# Unity3D tileset lags

Tags: unity-game-engine, tiled

Thin grey stripes appear when I move my character. They was all over the place with "Allow MSAA", but without appear randomly. To create maps I use Tiled and Tiled2Unity. What should I do to fix it?
[Allow MSAA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KswoM.png)
[not Allow MSAA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpAiX.png)

Answer (score 0):

See the following guide about this: http://tiled2unity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixing-seams/

Answer (score 0):

The linked screenshot looks like you are working with pixel art. In this case I would disable anti aliasing, as it's usually the aesthetic to go with this pixel-perfect art style.

Other than that, if you want to keep anti aliasing, you can create a 1 or 2 pixel border around your sprites and let them overlap. Of course now you don't have pixel-perfect graphics, but if you want it smooth, this is probably the best way to go.